# Appending build object to collection when fetching collection with build object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.2.3

Two model are associated as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User controller has an action as:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @documents = @user.documents   # List document
    @document =  @user.documents.build   # Build document
  end
end
```

Here, I want `@documents` variable to just contains the collection of the User's Document. But it is also appending a new instance of the `Document` `#<Document:0x007f2d28431550 id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 2>` also, which I don't want.

Say a `@user` has two Document associated to it.
Just after `List Document` Step `@documents` variable has value like:

```
[#<Document:0x007f2d290b67d0
  id: 95,
  document: "doc1.pdf",
  created_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:16 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:16 UTC +00:00,
  user_id: 2>,
#<Document:0x008f8d290e87da
  id: 96,
  document: "doc2.pdf",
  created_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:22 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:22 UTC +00:00,
  user_id: 2>]
```

and `@documents.count = 2`

But, after `Build document` step `@documents` variable has value like:

```
[#<Document:0x007f2d290b67d0
  id: 95,
  document: "doc1.pdf",
  created_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:16 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:16 UTC +00:00,
  user_id: 2>,
#<Document:0x008f8d290e87da
  id: 96,
  document: "doc2.pdf",
  created_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:22 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 04:32:22 UTC +00:00,
  user_id: 2>,
#<Document:0x007f2d28431550 id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 2> ]
```

but we still have `@documents.count = 2`.

Here, `count` is same. But the collection contain the one more object. 
How I can understand this behavior of rails. Also how I can freeze `@documents` to get only the collection of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@documents = @user.documents` adds a reference to the `@user.documents` array. `@user.documents.build` mutates that array in place, so `@documents` will always show the new record.

You have two options to resolve this:

Initialize `@document` as a `Document` and set the foreign key manually instead of going through  `@documents`. This will not add the new record to `@user.documents`

```
@documents = @user.documents
@document = Document.new(user: @user)
```

Make a copy of the `documents` array using `#dup` instead of referencing it.

```
@documents = @user.documents.dup
@document = @user.documents.build
```

Comment: First method: 
`@documents = @user.documents`
`@document = Document.new(user: @user)`
is working as intended.
But, Next method:
`@documents = @user.documents.dup`
`@document = @user.documents.build`
is showing the similar behavior.
However, thanks for yours answers.

Comment: @ShreeRamNeupane: For the second case, make sure you're accessing `build` through `@user.documents.build` instead of `@documents.build`. Works for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

`@documents` points to `@user`'s document. You should be building the new `document` on `@user` instead of `@member` to see the newly built document in your `@documents` collection.

Updating your `edit` action as follows should show you three documents for `@user` along with newly built document on `@document`:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @documents = @user.documents   # List document
    @document =  @documents.build   # Build document on `@user`.
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for type mistake, It should be `UsersController`, @user. I have corrected the question. However after doing `@document =  @documents.build` also, `@documents` is showing the same behavior.

Comment: @ShreeRamNeupane, I apologize I had missed the last line in your second code block where you have the newly built `Document` object. Am I correct to assume your original problem was related to using `.count` which makes a call to the database vs using `.size` which would have shown you three documents instead of two?